# Spark Structured Streaming with S3 fails comitting

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-structured-streaming

I'm running a Structured Streaming job on a Spark 2.2 cluster which is running on AWS. I'm using an S3 bucket in eu-central-1 for checkpointing.
Some commit actions on the workers seem to fail at random with the following error:

```
17/10/04 13:20:34 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 62.0 in stage 19.0 (TID 1946, 0.0.0.0, executor 0): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error committing version 1 into HDFSStateStore[id=(op=0,part=62),dir=s3a://bucket/job/query/state/0/62]
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$HDFSBackedStateStore.commit(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:198)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3$$anon$1.hasNext(statefulOperators.scala:230)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$4.apply(HashAggregateExec.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$4.apply(HashAggregateExec.scala:97)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXX, AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, AWS Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method., S3 Extended Request ID: abcdef==
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.copyObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1507)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyCallable.copyInOneChunk(CopyCallable.java:143)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyCallable.call(CopyCallable.java:131)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.copy(CopyMonitor.java:189)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.call(CopyMonitor.java:134)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.call(CopyMonitor.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
... 3 more
```

The job is subbmitted with the following options to allow eu-central-1 buckets:

```
--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.4
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=xxxxx
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=xxxxx
```

I already tried generating an access key without special chars and using instance policies, both had the same effect.

Comment: Don't use S3 for checkpointing. Since S3 provides only *eventual consistency* on read-after-write, there is no guarantee that when `HDFSBackedStateStore` lists the files, or tries to rename a file, it will exist in the S3 bucket even though it has just been previously written.

Comment: What else can I use? When using HDFS, eventually the change Log gets so large that it fails to start

Comment: Use HDFS. Which change log are we talking about?

Comment: HDFS change Log on the namenode

Comment: Make sure that you have the [SecondayNameNode](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/secondary-namenode---what-it-really-do/) active, it's supposed to compact and unify the edits file log, such that it won't take ages to start a namenode.

Comment: I just had one namenode and one datanode running, is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, most likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens so often the Hadoop team [provide a troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.md).

But like Yuval says: it's too dangerous to commit straight to S3, as well as getting slower-and-slower the more data you create, the risk of listing inconsistencies means that sometimes data gets lost, at least with the Apache Hadoop 2.6-2.8 versions of S3A

Comment: Yes, I’ve read through a lot of those but the problem isn’t always happening. So I guess it’s a folder or file that isn’t there yet because of eventual consistency

Comment: no, not that: that'd surface as a FileNotFoundException. This is authentication, and its not easy to track down, especially because for security reasons, the code doesn't dare log useful information like the specific secrets used.

If it's only against frankfurt, probably a v4 api issue

Answer (score 0):

Your logs says that :

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status
>   Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXX, AWS
>   Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, AWS Error Message: The request
>   signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
>   Check your key and signing method., S3 Extended Request ID: abcdef==

That error means the credentials aren't correct.

```
 val credentials = new com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials(
  "ACCESS_KEY_ID", 
  "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
  )
```

For debugging purpose

1) Access Key/Secret Key are both valid

2) Bucket name is correct or not

3) Turn on logging in the CLI and compare it with the SDK

4) Enable SDK logging as documented here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-logging.html.

You need to provide the log4j jar and the example log4j.properties file.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/get-aws-keys.html